# Changing img src through jQuery: image won't refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to change  src dynamically through jquery in a Phonegap Build application, like this

```
$('#photo_profile').attr('src', fullPath).one("load", function(evt) {
                console.log("load");
            }).each(function() {
              if(this.complete) $(this).load();
            });
```

But it seems that the img does not refresh while the "load" log is shown each time I change the src.

`fullPath` is something like `file:///storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder/Media/Profile%20Photos/profile.jpg`

And it's a valid path, as if I kill the app, then re-launch it, the  displays the correct image.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like caching issue. Try to prevent it with some random parameter:

```
$('#photo_profile').prop('src', fullPath + '?' + Math.random())
```

Also `src` is a property, so it makes sense to use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: Thanks dfsq! It works like a charm. I thought that it's a browser only concern, and not an issue in a phonegap application.