# img src not changed in jQuery script in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I have img

```
 <img src="captcha.jpg" id="my-image"/>
```

and jQuery script for change captcha image

```
<script>
    $(document).ready($("#my-image").click(function(){
        $('#my-image').attr('src', "captcha.jpg");
                        alert('adfgf');
    }));
</script>
```

when i click to image triggered image change and call alert in chrome. But in Firefox and in IE alert is called but image not changed. How fix it?

**EDIT**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/captcha.jpg", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void captcha(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.captcha(req, resp);
    }
```

Comment: You have malformed the ready handler.

Comment: You're changing the image src from `captcha.jpg` to `captcha.jpg` (which normally does nothing), is it normal ?

Answer (score 2):

You made an error using the [`ready` handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), you need to pass it a function.

Here's what you should do instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-image").click(function(){
        $('#my-image').attr('src', "captcha.jpg");
        alert('adfgf');
    });
});
```

**EDIT :** I included a snippet with an example to show you that it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-image").click(function(){
        $('#my-image').attr('src', "//placehold.it/100x100");
        alert('adfgf');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/50x50" id="my-image"/>
```

**EDIT n°2 :** And if you just want to reload/refresh your image, you can use :

```
$('#my-image').attr('src', "captcha.jpg" + Math.random())
```

[(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802073/changing-img-src-through-jquery-image-wont-refresh)

Comment: What is your complete HTML code ? Did you include jQuery ? (I included a snippet to show you that it works)

Comment: I edided my answer in case you just want to reload/refresh your image (doing another call to `captcha.jpg`)